# Inserting a predetermined datetime value into SQL table

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, datetime, pymssql

**Question: how do I insert a datetime value into MS SQL server, given the code below?**

**Context:**

I have a 2-D list (i.e., a list of lists) in Python that I'd like to upload to a table in Microsoft SQL Server 2008. For this project I am using Python's `pymssql` package. Each value in each list is a string except for the very first element, which is a datetime value.
Here is how my code reads:

```
import pymssql

db_connect = pymssql.connect( # these are just generic names
    server = server_name,
    user = db_usr,
    password = db_pwd,
    database = db_name
    )

my_cursor = db_connect.cursor()
for individual_list in list_of_lists:
    # the first value in the paranthesis should be datetime 
    my_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO [DB_Table_Name] VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", tuple(individual_list))
    db_connect.commit()
```

The python interpreter is having a tough time inserting my datetime values. I understand that currently I have `%s` and that it is a string formatter, but I'm unsure what I should use for `datetime`, which is what the database's first column is formatted as.

The "list of lists" looks like this (after each list is converted into a tuple):

```
[(datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 1), '1', '4.1', 'hip', 'A1', 'J. Smith', 'B123', 'XYZ'),...]
```

Here is an illustration of what the table should look like:

```
+-----------+------+------+--------+-------+-----------+---------+---------+
|    date   | step | data |  type  |   ID  |  contact  | notif.  | program |
+-----------+------+------+--------+-------+-----------+---------+---------+
|2012-04-01 |   1  | 4.1  |   hip  |   A1  | J. Smith  |   B123  |   XYZ   |
|2012-09-05 |   2  | 5.1  |   hip  |   A9  | B. Armst  |   B123  |   ABC   |
|2012-01-16 |   5  | 9.0  | horray |   C6  | F. Bayes  |   P995  |   XYZ   |
+-----------+------+------+--------+-------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you show the columns in the table and sample data from the list?

Comment: @vkp see my edits above- thanks!

Comment: Your code looks reasonable to me. How is the problem manifesting itself? Error message? Unexpected date values being inserted? ...?

Answer (score 0):

I would try formatting the date time to "yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss" before inserting. With what you are doing SQL will be parsing the string so I would also build the entire string and then insert the string as a variable. See below

```
for individual_list in list_of_lists:
    # the first value in the parentheses should be datetime 
    date_time = individual_list[0].strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
    insert_str = "INSERT INTO [DB_Table_Name] VALUES (" + str(date_time) + "),(" + str(individual_list[1]) + ");"
    print insert_str
    my_cursor.execute(insert_str)
    db_connect.commit()
```

I apologize for the crude python but SQL should like that insert statement as long as all the fields match up.  If not you may want to specify what fields those values go to in your insert statement.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: This is part of a web scraping project; I already have the dates in string format. The problem is that the database I'm working with has the date column formatted as `datetime`. If there's no way to upload datetime type values, I'll just have to create a new database column as "varchar" and upload what I have as strings. I was wondering if there was a way to upload the values as datetime values, though, not as strings.

Comment: That is correct.  There is no way that I know of to add a python date time object to a SQL field.  it needs to be in a date time format that SQL recognizes in an insert string.

Comment: (cc: @daOnlyBG) The way to do it is with a *parameterized query*: `crsr.execute("UPDATE table1 SET dtmcol=%s WHERE ID=%s", (datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 10), 3))`

Comment: @GordThompson I recommend you post that as an answer rather than leave it in the comments!